# Convert a grid of adjacent squares into an outline

Tags: java, graphics, pseudocode

I have a bit of a strange problem to solve. Ask not if it is practical, but if it is possible. Imagine a monochrome bitmap where all black pixels must be adjacent to each other. How could you convert this into an ordered set of points that describe the outline of the black shape?

I understand that you can create a set of lines from this data fairly easily, for example a quick and dirty solution:

```java
// int array: x1, y1, x2, y2
List<int[]> lines = new ArrayList();
for (int x=0; x < BITMAP_WIDTH; x++) {
     for (int y=0; y < BITMAP_HEIGHT; y++) {
          // X and Y values outside of the valid range are considered white pixels
          boolean value = getPixel(x, y);
          if (value) {
               boolean left = getPixel(x - 1, y);
               boolean right = getPixel(x + 1, y);
               boolean top = getPixel(x, y - 1);
               boolean bottom = getPixel(x, y + 1);
               if (!left) lines.add(new int[]{ x, y, x, y + 1 });
               if (!top) lines.add(new int[]{ x, y, x + 1, y });
               if (!right) lines.add(new int[]{ x + 1, y, x + 1, y + 1 });
               if (!bottom) lines.add(new int[]{ x, y + 1, x + 1, y + 1 });
          }
     }
}
```

But the challenge comes from ordering those points in such a way that they connect back-to-back. I imagine there's a pretty simple way of doing this but it's just not coming to me, at least not a method that would take a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Is this correct? You have a contiguous block of "black" pixels, they form a shape, and you want to find those pixels that are on the perimeter?  And you want those in some sort of order?    Is it possible to have  "white" islands inside the "black" area?  If so, how do you want that handled?

Comment: @James Yes, if you see the example this produces a list of lines that describe the outer edge of the black shape. The problem is ordering those points such that they connect back-to-back and define a polygon: so either in roughly clockwise or anticlockwise order.

Comment: One approach might be to find a starting set pixel that borders an unset pixel. Then, look for adjacent set pixels that border unset pixels. Move to one, and continue, ignoring set pixels that have already been visited. However, that approach is challenged by filaments.  Even more difficult to handle would be branched filaments.

Comment: I might try an approach based on a right (or left) hand rule. Find an unset pixel adjacent to a set pixel. Keep  track of your orientation, i.e., facing up, right, down, or left. If the adjacent pixel you are facing is unset, move in that direction and check the pixel adjacent to that. If set, repeat. If unset, turn (change orientation) to the right and move on. If facing a set pixel, turn to the left.

Comment: I didn't submit my previous comment as an answer, because I don't know that it will surely work. But, I might like to try to code that myself. Do you have any example bitmaps  you could share to test it on?

Comment: What if your shape has filaments? How is the order defined?  A filament would be sequence with width = 1 of set pixels.

Comment: The first approach I suggested can be made to work. Backtracking is done with a "right hand rule", keeping outside (unset) pixels to the right.

Answer (score 1):

I think an approach based on the "right hand rule" should work. Imagine the pixels or cells are physical objects, say each 8 feet in height, 3 feet wide, and 3 feet thick. To someone on the outside, the perimeter is a wall. Someone on the outside walks around it, keeping the right hand on the wall, until returning to the starting point. The tracer records the position of each cell touched.

Note that all the corners are at right angles. There are outside corners, where the tracer makes right turns. There are inside corners, where a left turn is made.

The tracer follows a path just outside the perimeter and tests adjacent cells.  When the tracer finds the cell to the right is not set, the tracer makes a right turn. When the tracer is facing an occupied cell, a left turn is made.

Note, when coming to an inside corner, where a left turn is made, a cell that is diagonal to the one where the turn is made is included in the trace, even though the tracer didn't touch it. It's existence is implied by the contiguous rule.

Note that this results in pixels in filaments being included twice: Once when following the filament out, and again when following the filament in.

If the tracer is following a line that is 45° off vertical, the tracer might, for example, move 1 cell up, then 1 cell left, then 1 up, 1 left, and so on. If following a line that is 30° off vertical, the tracer might move 2 cells right, then 1 up, 2 right, 1 up, and so on.

Comment: I'd like to see this in action. I've written most of the code for such a tracer. But, to test it out, I'll want code to display the bitmap in a GUI.